# Is there an efficient implementation of tetration?

Tags: algorithm, math

After recently answering a question involving the Ackerman function part of which involved a function for computing the tetration of a number. Which led me to ponder if there was a more efficient way to do it. I did some testing on my own but I'm limited mainly by the fact that even a number such as 5^^3=5^3125 given 5^3  is roughly 10^2, meaning 5^3125 ~= 10^(3125*2/3) around 2000 digits.

The function doesn't lend itself to divide and conquer methods due to the nature of how the exponentiation is done, ie:

2^^5=2^(2^(2^(2^2))))=2^(2^(2^4))=2^(2^16)=2^65536~=10^(65536*3/10) so around 20k digits...

The nature of the problem, since it begins at the top of the power tree and works it way down strikes me as factorial. A fast power algorithm can be used to do the exponentiation operation obviously, but I haven't been able to see a way to shrink the number of exponentiation operations.

In case anyone is unclear what I'm talking about here's the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) , essentially though tetration is:

a^^b= a^a^a....^a, b times and then starting the exponentiation at the top element of the power tree and working down.

The algorithm I'm currently using would be (although I'm using a ruby version if I actually want values):

```
long int Tetration(int number, int tetrate)
{
    long int product=1;
    if(tetrate==0)
        return product;
    product=number;
    while(tetrate>1)
    {
        product=FastPower(number,product);
        tetrate--;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that a lot depends on what kind of numerical representation you need.  Do you need exact integer representation?  Or is approximate numerical (floating-point) representation sufficient?

Comment: It's purely a question out of curiosity, so I'd be curious to see how you could write a more efficient algorithm with floating point representation.

Comment: I did look into this but quickly realized that the integer digits length problem (which Dave explains below) will also afflict the exponent of any tetration function output, just at one recursion less.  Basically, floating-point can handle exponentiation products because it is a LOG formatted representation.  IMO, to efficiently handle tetration products, you would need to develop a superLog based format.  This sounds difficult but interesting, maybe even thesis worthy (Masters anyway).

Comment: And what's the best way to calculate things such as 11^9^7^5^3 mod 117 ?.  It should be some easier way because I don't need all the numbers, just the remainder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With tetration, if the final answer is d digits, then all intermediate results are O(log d) digits, as opposed to O(d) digits with exponentiation. Because the intermediate results for tetration are so small compared to the final result, there's no savings to be had via divide and conquer. It's also unlikely that there is a useful way to save exponentiation operations in a unit-cost RAM, since exponentiation isn't associative.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the world record for the biggest grave dig ever, but incase anyone else stumbles upon this: This is p5.js, but just use the part within the section labeled Tetration algorithm.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Tetration</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.6.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(255);
  print(tetra(prompt("Enter a"),prompt("Enter b")));
}

//Tetration algorithm
function tetra(a,b) {
  let c = a;
  for(let i = 1; i < b; i++){c = pow(a,c);}
  return(c);
}
```

You can use the above function and integrate it into your code.

Answer (score -3):

I dont think that there is a simple way to do tetration,
So I did This:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                var x = 1
                //That is ▽ The Number You Are Powering//
                var test = 3
                var test2 = test
                setInterval (function () {
                    // that is  ▽ How many times you power it so this would be 3 tetra 3      which is 7625597484987//
                    if (x < 3) {
                        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = test=test2**test
                        x++
                    }
                }, 1);
            </script>
            <p id="test">0</p>
```